# Filtering between Select Box Salary ranges using DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I'm trying to filter Salaries in a DataTable using a select box but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here's the select box:

```
<select class="custom-select w-100" name="salary" id="salary">
<option value="" selected="selected">Any salary</option>
<option value="18000">£18,000 and below</option>
<option value="28000">£28,000 and below </option>
<option value="32000">£32,000 and below</option>
<option value="40000">£40,000 and above</option>
</select>
```

And here's the query:

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
      var salary = parseFloat( data[2].replace(",","") ) || 0;
      return salary <= parseInt($('#salary').val())
      });

$('#salary').on( 'change', function (data) {
        table.draw();
      });
```

Here's a picture of the table: [image]

Does anyone know what I'm doing fundamentally wrong? I imagine it's something obvious..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this: you need to replace pound sign too along with comma

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
      var salary = data[2].replace(",","");
          salary = salary.replace("£","");
          salary = parseFloat(salary) || 0;
      var selectedText = $('#salary option:selected').text();
      if(selectedText.indexOf('excellent')!=-1) {
        return false;
      } else if(selectedText.indexOf('above')!=-1) {
        return salary > parseInt($('#salary').val());
      } else {
        return salary <= parseInt($('#salary').val());
      }
 });
```

Comment: What happens with "*£40,000 and above*" ...? Also, would it no be much easier with a regex?

Comment: updated my post but still it does not seem to be perfect answer

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar Thanks! That worked a treat. Do you think it'd be possible to filter out rows with text data such as "excellent"?

Comment: Yes, this is possible by simply returning false for row containing "excellent", please check my updated post